# Can we create a list definition in SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Can we create a list definition in SharePoint framework?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

You can create a list in SharePoint online using SharePoint Framework.

Please check below references for detailed information:

**References**:

1. [SharePoint Framework : Provision Custom List with Site Columns and Content Type](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Framework-b721fcd6).
2. [Provision custom list using SharePoint Framework](https://www.sharepoint-journey.com/Provision-Custom-List-using-SharePoint-Framework.html).